# How to make payment directly from a Html form

Tags: javascript, html, checkout

I have a form that allows users to input their details before making a payment. How can I copy these input values from the HTML to the payment code gateway without saving the input values in a database table?

**This is my HTML Form**

```
     <form>
          <label>Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="full_name" />
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" />
          <label>Amount (NGN)</label>
          <input type="number"  name="amount" placeholder="Min Amount 1000"/>
          <script src="https://js.paystack.co/v1/inline.js"></script>
          <button type="button" onclick="payWithPaystack()"> Pay </button> 
     </form>
```

**And this is the payment code**

```
<script>
            function payWithPaystack(){
              var handler = PaystackPop.setup({
                key: 'pk_test_f5e677',
                email: 'customer@email.com',
                amount: 10000,
                currency: "NGN",
                ref: ''+Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1), // generates a pseudo-unique reference. Please replace with a reference you generated. Or remove the line entirely so our API will generate one for you
                metadata: {
                   custom_fields: [
                      {
                          display_name: "Mobile Number",
                          variable_name: "mobile_number",
                          value: "+2348012345678"
                      }
                   ]
                },
                callback: function(response){
                    alert('success. transaction ref is ' + response.reference);
                },
                onClose: function(){
                    alert('window closed');
                }
              });
              handler.openIframe();
            }
          </script>
```

Comment: Store your form values in an Object and assign it the gateway API

Comment: @Masood, please, I will appreciate if you show me how by demonstration

Answer (score 0):

Like so...

In the code below, we get the elements containing the information and then, during the function call, we get the values of those elements.

```
<form>
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" id=“nameField” name="full_name" />
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" id=“emailField” name="email" />
    <label>Amount (NGN)</label>
    <input type="number" id=“amountField” name="amount" placeholder="Min Amount 1000"/>
    <script src="https://js.paystack.co/v1/inline.js"></script>
    <button type="button" onclick="payWithPaystack()"> Pay </button> 
</form>


<script>
    var email = document.getElementById(“emailField”);
    var name = document.getElementById(“nameField”);
    var amount = document.getElementById(“amountField”);
    function payWithPaystack(){
        var handler = PaystackPop.setup({
            key: 'pk_test_f5e677',
            email: email.value,
            amount: amount.value,
            currency: "NGN",
            ref: ''+Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1), // generates a pseudo-unique reference. Please replace with a reference you generated. Or remove the line entirely so our API will generate one for you
             metadata: {
                custom_fields: [
                {
                    display_name: "Mobile Number",
                    variable_name: "mobile_number",
                    value: "+2348012345678"
               }]
            },
            callback: function(response){
                alert('success. transaction ref is ' + response.reference);
            },
            onClose: function(){
                alert('window closed');
            }
        });
        handler.openIframe();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello @Benjamin, I tried working with your code above but I got this error on the variable in quotes "Invalid Character"